# Finding the end of a dynamic list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a report that has an employee name, and then, 1 to 14 rows below them.

I am able to find the row for a specific employee but need to SUM up a column in the rows beneath them.  I am able to do all this, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to find the last row that pertains to them.

I have made a solution using VBA, but I am wanting to know if there is a way with out using VBA.

Thanks,

Comment: please provide sample data in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You could name the range and refer to the named range in your formula so if you insert and delete rows you can just amend the range or, if possible, you can insert or delete cells in the middle of the range and it'll update automatically.

You could also potentially store the rows underneath as a table which will increase in size as you fill in cells underneath it and then sum the table's column.

Comment: I think @B Slater has the best solution, but if you want to just use something in a formula, you might try using COUNTA, extending the range you want to check, and it will return only the number of cells that are not empty.